# How do i fetch Buddypress private message to send in rest api?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am creating wordpress rest api there is buddypress plugin install in my site. I want to fetch the private message for the user. I am not able to find the same. i go though the several thread but every thing for template and for website. i want to fetch the data and return in JSON to my rest api response for mobile.

So any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this project [A RESTful API, for BuddyPress](https://github.com/buddypress/BP-REST), which is done by the official team behind BuddyPress.

BP Messages endpoint is already implemented, you can check the code here: https://github.com/buddypress/BP-REST/blob/master/includes/bp-messages/classes/class-bp-rest-messages-endpoint.php

Comment: Thank You So much Slava Abakumov, Yes i got that previously but i am not sure what should be the url and how do i fetch private message of a user from it's friend list.